# Differences in string references (functions)

Tags: c++, string, recursion, reference

Is there a difference between string& str and string &str?

For example:

```
reverse (const string& str) {
   }
```

vs

```
reverse (const string &str) {
   }
```

probably a dumb question but...

Comment: In what language? c, c++, Java, etc. I'm guessing c++.

Comment: sorry, yes, C++

Comment: In that case, no I don't think so. C++ usually isn't very picky about whitespace. I'm sure someone else will have a better answer though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. They are same in C++. Prefer `const string&`.
Function declaration does not ask for variable name itself. Here, data type is `const string&`

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing in c++

Comment: Explain your logic, and give a little commentary so that it can help future readers as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference . But it is a good coding practice to follow any one convention throughout your code.